# checking Azure Data catalog using logic apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-data-catalog

I want to make a logic app that will send an email if Azure data catalog goes down for one of our subscriptions.  I know i can ping it but wanted to know if there was a built in trigger or action to test of services.

Comment: Are you having problems with your Azure Services such that you need to keep checking things?  The Azure service SLA is proven high enough that this isn't something everyone else really thinks about.  If your apps are crashing, you should spend the time fixing them instead of monitoring them.